# n by n board editor

Tags: online, chessboards

I was trying to do some animations using a chessboard and it turns out that I need an *n*-by-*n* board editor (for some *n* less than 16). Are there any such editors available online? I would like to have some ready-made links.

I don't even want to analyze any positions, I just want to place some pieces of my choice.

Comment: Dunno one, but it sounds like a beginners exercise in Javascript :-) (Either with nxn drop-down buttons, for better visualization, or with three, rank, file, piece.)

Answer (score 3):

This board editor is excellent https://musketeerchess.net/tools/boardpainter/.

Comment: It is! Just too bad you can't enter moves and play it back.